# Javascript Generating a random number that can be divided by 5

Tags: javascript

Is it possible and if so, how can one generate a random number that can be divided by 5, for example: 5, 10, 15, 20 using the `Math.random()` function in Javascript?

Comment: Just generate random number and multiply by 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below snippet for generate number.

```
var d=(Math.round(Math.random()*10))*5; console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `random()` into an integer, and then multiply the integer by 5:

```js
const randomDivisibleBy5 = (chunks) => (
  Math.floor(Math.random() * chunks) * 5
);
console.log(randomDivisibleBy5(3)); // 0 to 10
console.log(randomDivisibleBy5(3));
console.log(randomDivisibleBy5(9)); // 0 to 85
console.log(randomDivisibleBy5(9));
console.log(randomDivisibleBy5(30)); // 0 to 145
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work for you.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*5
```

Answer (score -1):

well yes, easily. Use `Math.random() * 5`

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a float between 0 and 1. This won’t work.